# Big Data process stack after 25k users

Tags: java, linux, performance, recommendation-engine, bigdata

I have a dataset with 28k users, 60k locations and 1m reviews. I am implementing a recommender system with take into concideration common locations and common rates that users have been to make in the end some predictions about how much a user would like to go to a location.

Here is the code of how I am doing it

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> user_locIDVisitsPredictions = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> user_locIDRatesPredictions = new HashMap<>();          


List<Future> tasks1 = new ArrayList<>();
ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
for(String me : wholeSetHistory.keySet()){
    Runnable tokentask = new UserRun(wholeSetHistory, wholeSetRatings, lnglatStores2, user_locIDVisitsPredictions, user_locIDRatesPredictions, me, u);
    u++;
    tasks1.add(executor1.submit(tokentask));
}
executor1.shutdown();
boolean done1=false;
while(done1==false) {
    done1=true;
    for (int i=0; i<tasks1.size(); i++){
        try{
            Future future =tasks1.get(i);
            if(future.get()!=null){
                done1=false;
                break;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("sto future kollise ");
        }
    }
}
tasks1.clear();
```

Runnable tokentask is implementing the process for one user to get the results for him. I am using threads because I run the experiment on a machine that is away and it runs on Linux OS. I run it with nohub.

And now my problem. The process is going great until it hits 25k users. The last 3k users is taking for ever to compute the results for them.

Some more details about how the algorithm works.

1. for a target user
2. for every other user that is near the target user

   2.1 get the locations he has been and compare with target user

   2.2 get the rates he has done and compare with target user

   2.3 make similarities

   2.4 make predictions

Any ideas why the process is going very slow after 25k users?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It might be issue with memory what is the jvm max heap size

Comment: Note that it is not necessary the absolute heap size that matters, but that it is big *enough*

Answer (score 0):

I would use far less tasks.  I am guessing the `wholeSetHistory` is the 1m collection, however you only need 1 to 2 tasks per CPU.  Fortunately there is a built in library which does this for you.

```
List<Result> results = wholeSetHistory.entrySet().parallelStream(e ->
    new UserRun(e.getValue(), wholeSetRatings, lnglatStores2, 
                user_locIDVisitsPredictions, user_locIDRatesPredictions, e.getKey())
    .result())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will dramatically reduce the number of objects you have created at once, and the code is much simpler.  You also don't have a busy waiting thread burning a CPU.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a parallel stream, because it uses a common (shared) thread pool and will interfere (exhaust the shared threads) with other parallel streams

Comment: @SvetlinZarev If you are using all the CPUs already, you are says that adding more work will slow down anything running? How would you prevent this from being a problem without using more hardware?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev using two thread pools doesn't mean you have more CPUs.

Comment: If he uses it's own dedicated pool, then his jobs will *work in parallel*, but if he's using a shared one - they *may wait* until a thread becomes available - it's not about slowness or more CPUs. This might be an issue, or might be not. It's up to him to decide.

Comment: Imagine you have 2 tasks - the 2nd depends on the 1st and a shared pool with 1 thread. You submit the second ask and it blocks. Then you submit the first - and here you a have a deadlock.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev blocking on jobs to a thread pool inside a thread pool is a bad idea.  In fact using a thread pool inside a thread pool at all is a bad idea, once you are using all the CPU on the machine, adding more tasks just adds overhead.  However, the ForkJoinPool uses work stealing which means that when it blocks on a ForkJoinPooll it is in it can steal work and execute it while it is waiting. This has the side effect of adding the blocking thread to the pool which is a potentially surprising outcome.

Comment: I've never said anything about a thread pool inside a thread pool.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I am sorry and struggling to work out your point. When you use a ForkJoinPool, you always have one thread which is still yours.  You generally don't want to use more threads than you have CPUs and using two thread pools is likely to mean more overhead and context switching so your progam will be slower. The ForkJoinPool does create many tasks per thread so you don't have to wait for the pool to be free befor eyour tasks start.  In short, unless care is taken, using multiple pools is not only more complex and error prone it can be slower.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev using multiple pools makes sense when you want to limit the impact of certain operations on other tasks and applications running on your system.  However, there is nothing in the question which suggests this is needed.